# Where to place generic methods in Rails?

Tags: ruby, inheritance, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to load icons for use in a sidebar in main layout. So the methods I need must

1. Load icons path into a variable
2. Use this variable to load each icon's path into one array @icons_paths
3. Render all icons through something like (haml)

> @icons_paths.each do |i_p|
>        .some-bs-class
>          .a-nother-class
>            link_to image_tag(i_p, alt: ""), some_path

This probably shouldn't go to a view, as it is logic too heavy, or am i wrong?
And I'd like the sidebar to be a partial, just as header and footer.

I want to make this code reusable, so the question is **where do I put these methods and why?** I can't fit them into any specific controller nor model.

PS. Sorry for formatting, I indented code by 4 spaces - no effect.

Comment: I'd put in in a partial. It doesn't look like there's a lot of logic there? Just looping through an array and outputting some html for each element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a partial would be fine for that content, but if you *really* want to store it somewhere other than a partial, then define a **helper method** in `app/views/helpers/application_helper.rb` (or `foo_helper.rb`):

```
def clickable_icons
  content = ""
  @icons_paths.each do |i_p|
    content << link_to(image_tag(i_p, alt: ""), some_path, {class: "some-bs-class a-nother-class"})
  end
  content.html_safe
end
```

And in your `app/views/some_view.html.haml`:

```
= clickable_icons
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best practice in this case would be placing the methods code in your resource's helper file and then call the helper from your view or partial, even if the logic isn't much you shouldn't place it in your view file. so if your resource name is "events", it would be something like this:

```
#app/helpers/events_helper.rb
def method_name
  # code goes here
end`
```

and you just call it in your view/partial:

```
# app/views/events/view_name.html.haml
%aside
  = method_name
```